# Как в mariaDB сделать поле Рейтинг, которое считает количество лайков, поставленных пользователями

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mariadb

Хочу сделать поле в БД MariaDB в таблице песня. Называется поле Рейтинг. Думаю сделать так чтобы один пользователь ставил лайк к определенной песне и в поле автоматический увеличивалось на +1.

Пытался искать тип данных в бд, который может считать ,но ни в одной БД их не нашел

Comment: Есть такие поля. Например: CREATE TABLE order_details (price DOUBLE, quantity INT, amount DOUBLE AS (price * quantity));

Answer (score 0):

Если рейтинг - это количество лайков, то тут логично будет использовать целочисленный тип `INT`. Разумеется, сама БД и это поле ничего не знаю о функциональности количества голосов за песню, это Вы уже с помощью запросов будете реализовывать.
После лайка, Ваш бэкэнд будет выполнять примерной такой запрос:

```
UPDATE song
SET rating = rating + 1
WHERE id = id_value;
```